# How to use -n flag in a sed script, I used it and it is giving error

Tags: regex, bash, sed

```
$ sed -n '/<body>/,/<\/body>/p' hello.html
```

The command works fine and gives desired result.
I want to print only those which lines between  and  (including these tags as well) of an `html` file named as `hello.html`

But when I try to create a `sed` script named as `html-body.sed` with this command as:

```
-n /<body>/,/<\/body>/p
```

when I try to run it....

```
$ sed -f html-body.sed hello.html
```

It gives error as:

```
sed: file html-body.sed line 1: unknown command: `-'
```

**Why this same command, when written in `sed` script gives this error.**

Comment: you can't use any `-` options inside a script file with sed

Comment: As @Jidder says, you can't put sed command line arguments into the sed program script file. You can either put the entire sed command into the script or use -n on the command line yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The `sed` script is only allowed to hold `sed` *text processing commands,* not options to `sed` itself.

Those options are required to be on the actual command invocation.

You can still *use* a `sed` script but you have to call it *with* the options:

```
sed -n html-body.sed hello.html
```

One thing you *can* do is switch to a more powerful text processing tool such as `awk` with the following script:

```
/<body>/   {e=1}
           {if(e==1){print}}
/<\/body>/ {e=0}
```

Then simply run:

```
awk -f thatscript.awk inputfile
```